# Debugging the WPF Visual Tree from MS Word Add-In

Tags: wpf, ms-word, vsto

I have a MS Word VSTO Add-In that references an assembly with a number of WPF windows. The Live Visual Tree and Live Property Explorer (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7-XynTD_mI) show nothing when I debug.

Should they work in this scenario? and if so, what am I doing wrong?